# changing background color dynamically

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to set the background color of the label below [input](https://i.postimg.cc/MpLsD2t2/stack.png) tag dynamically but the label isn't visible in my visual studio. Is there any way to set the background color dynamically in `asp.net` c# for the tag which isn't visible in ?

```
<div class="sc-item">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSizes" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblSizes_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to a RB list with code, and when doing that, you can also set the color, or style, or whatever.

Say this markup:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And our code behind can be this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim OneChoice As ListItem

        OneChoice = New ListItem("Red", "Red")
        OneChoice.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color:red")
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(OneChoice)

        OneChoice = New ListItem("Blue", "Blue")
        OneChoice.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color:blue")
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(OneChoice)

        OneChoice = New ListItem("Green", "Green")
        OneChoice.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color:Green")
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(OneChoice)

    End If

End Sub
```

And now we get this:

[image]